# Build number Mismatch - a form of dll hell?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I've done the usual searching etc and can't quite decide on how to solve my issue.

I have an internal to my company windows forms app (.net 3.5 / VS 2010) that I ship to various users. One of the references in my project is to a database driver data.client.dll. This data.client.dll in turn references an unmanaged dll (data.clientsuppp.dll) that needs to be bundled into the distributable but I cannot add it as a reference in my project - it is simply put in the bin dir.

This had been fine for years until another app has released the same driver but an older version of the unmanaged dll. The older version of the unmanaged dll is now being picked up my app and presenting this error:

Message: Build number Mismatch - data.clientsuppp.dll. Expecting build number greater than or equal to '9000'. Loaded build number 1022.

I am not sure how to handle this, I expected the bin dir to be the first location looked at but it appears the path is being scanned first. Any tips on how to solve this would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's DLL Hell.  It is entirely unclear how the wrong version could get loaded until you use SysInternals' Process Monitor to see how it was found.

Comment: Or have a look at the output from [fusion log viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx)